# Picking element of a list in some order and store in a list with R

Tags: list, dataframe, for-loop, combinations

i've just write an example code. My aim is to create a list of DF. For example the first DF of the list have to be (vecA, vecC, vecE) the second (vecA, vecC, VecF) and so on, cover only combination.
Thank you so much!

```
vecA = c(1,2,3,4,4,6)
vecB = c(2,132,4)
vecC= c(11,32,73,14,45,67)
vecD= c(13,33,34)
vecE = c(61,62,73,74,78,79)
vecF = c(12,21,30)


a = data.frame(vecA, vecB)
b = data.frame(vecC, vecD)
c = data.frame(vecE, vecF)

abclist = list(a,b,c)

list_try = list()
for (m in 1:9) {
  for (i in 1:length(abclist[[1]])) {
    for (j in 1:length(abclist[[2]])) {
      for (k in 1:length(abclist[[3]])) {  
        list_try[[m]] = data.frame(abclist[[1]][i], 
                                   abclist[[2]][j],
                                   abclist[[3]][k])
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You an use `combn` to get all of the desired combinations that available (list of vectors, choose 3).

You can then use the output from the possible combinations to build your vectors. I used the `get` function which accepts a string, then looks in the environment for an object that name and returns the object. Like you did before, you can wrap this in a loop:

```
vecA = c(1,2,3,4,4,6)
vecB = c(2,132,4)
vecC= c(11,32,73,14,45,67)
vecD= c(13,33,34)
vecE = c(61,62,73,74,78,79)
vecF = c(12,21,30)

df_combos <- combn(c("vecA", "vecB", "vecC",
        "vecD", "vecE", "vecF"), 3)

list_try <- list()
for(i in 1:ncol(df_combos)){
  list_try[[i]] <- data.frame(a = get(df_combos[1,i]),
                              b = get(df_combos[2,i]),
                              c = get(df_combos[3,i]))
}
```

Which gives you:

```
[[1]]
  a   b  c
1 1   2 11
2 2 132 32
3 3   4 73
4 4   2 14
5 4 132 45
6 6   4 67

[[2]]
  a   b  c
1 1   2 13
2 2 132 33
3 3   4 34
4 4   2 13
5 4 132 33
6 6   4 34

[[3]]
  a   b  c
1 1   2 61
2 2 132 62
...
```